# Apache doesn't seem to point to vhost, serves files from wrong document root

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost

I am trying to troubleshoot an apache instance which was working fine until a reboot last week. It now appears as though the vhosts are not being loaded and I can't figure out why.

Any attempt to access app.domain.com, which should forward to the vhost's document root, actually points to the main server's document root.

The httpd.conf is below (with some minor obfuscations)

```
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"
Listen 80

Include conf.modules.d/*.conf

User web-user
Group web-group 

ServerAdmin me@domain.com

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

<Directory />
   AllowOverride all
   Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www">
    #Previous value none
    AllowOverride none 
    # Allow open access:
    Require all granted
</Directory>

# Further relax access to the default document root:
<Directory "/var/www/html">

    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks  
    AllowOverride all 
    Require all granted
</Directory>

################### VHOST Directory #######################
<Directory "/apps/app/public_html">
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
  Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>

<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>

ErrorLog "logs/error_log"
LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>

    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
      # You need to enable mod_logio.c to use %I and %O
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>

    CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"

</IfModule>


<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig /etc/mime.types
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mime_magic_module>
    MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>

EnableSendfile on

IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

The vhost.conf file located in sites-enabled

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName app.domain.com
  ServerAlias app.domain.com
  DocumentRoot /apps/app/public_html
  ErrorLog /var/www/app/error_log
  CustomLog /var/www/app/access_log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I also have a .htaccess file in the primary document root (/var/www/html) that redirects any plaintext traffic to the SSL website.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://app.domain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Is anyone able to identify the error in my config?

EDIT : Result of httpd -S

```
[root@server]# httpd -S
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using app.domain.com. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
VirtualHost configuration:
*:443                  is a NameVirtualHost
         default server app.domain.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:56)
         port 443 namevhost app.domain.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:56)
         port 443 namevhost app.domain.com (/etc/httpd/sites-enabled/app.conf:1)
                 alias app.domain.com
ServerRoot: "/etc/httpd"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/etc/httpd/logs/error_log"
Mutex authdigest-opaque: using_defaults
Mutex proxy-balancer-shm: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex authdigest-client: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
Mutex proxy: using_defaults
Mutex authn-socache: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/run/httpd/" mechanism=default
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
PidFile: "/run/httpd/httpd.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="web-user" id=1001
Group: name="web-group" id=1001
```

Comment: Check the output of "apachectl -S". Also I don't see the reason why for such a simple redirect you are using .htaccess and mod_rewrite, but that's out of the question. Also, remove Order/Allow/Deny and leave only Require (2.4) directives if you don't want unexpected behaviour later on.

Comment: @ezra-s edited to include httpd -S. If you have a better way to do the redirection to HTTPS I'm happy to take suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is right now you have the same virtualhost defined in two different files, so the first one is the one being used:

```
port 443 namevhost app.domain.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:56)
```

While **this other is being ignored**:

```
port 443 namevhost app.domain.com (/etc/httpd/sites-enabled/app.conf:1)
```

Never define two virtualhosts with the ServerName, because if you do, first match will get all requests and the second virtualhost will be ignored.